# compute_face_descriptor() alternative in C++

Tags: python, c++, face-recognition, dlib

In python API of [dlib](http://dlib.net/) there is a function called [`compute_face_descriptor()`](http://dlib.net/python/#dlib.face_recognition_model_v1) but I couldn't find any alternative to it in C++ API.

How can I create an alternative to it in C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`compute_face_descriptor()` is coming from `dlib.face_recognition_model_v1(face_recognition_model)`

`face_recognition_model` contains `dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1.dat`

see here [https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition_models/blob/master/face_recognition_models/**init**.py](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition_models/blob/master/face_recognition_models/__init__.py)

```
face_recognition_model = face_recognition_models.face_recognition_model_location()
face_encoder = dlib.face_recognition_model_v1(face_recognition_model)

.....

def face_encodings(face_image, known_face_locations=None, num_jitters=1):
    raw_landmarks = _raw_face_landmarks(face_image, known_face_locations, model="small")
    return [np.array(face_encoder.compute_face_descriptor(face_image, raw_landmark_set, num_jitters)) for raw_landmark_set in raw_landmarks]
```

Answer (score 2):

A very quick perusing through dlib's source code reveals that this function is implemented in tools/python/src/face_recognition.cpp.

So all you have to do is bring that code into your project. It being licensed under the BOOST license makes it simple.

Answer (score 1):

There is a C++ example program that comes with dlib that shows how to do this: http://dlib.net/dnn_face_recognition_ex.cpp.html

Comment: Which piece of code is the exact replacement of ``compute_face_descriptor()`` ?